# How can I replicate a user created table?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, macos

This is a part of the iTunes smart playlist creation window; for my application I need to create something very similar to this:

[image]

The changes I'll be making would be the column that says artist would be integers (but still a pop up button), same with the second column. The third column would be text input like in the picture. I would like to keep the functionality of the "+" and "-" buttons but I don't have much use for the "..." button. Is there any easy way to recreate this? I need the user to be able to add as many or few fields as necessary. 
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need to support 10.4, take a look at NSPredicateEditor. It should allow you to easily recreate iTunes' interface with the changes you describe.  http://nvie.com/posts/nspredicateeditor-tutorial/ may be useful to help you get started.